# Floating Toolbar with Appcompat

Tags: toolbar, android, android-appcompat

How to create a floating toolbar like the following image as proposed in the material design guidelines and in the Google Map application.

[image]

Comment: Off the cuff, I would assume that you would use `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` as the container for the map and the `Toolbar`. Having the `Toolbar` as a later child in the container will give it higher elevation and have it float over the map surface.

Comment: Yes. That works to get the Toolbar to float over the map surface. But how to give the Toolbar the 'detached' feel (as in the picture)? . Thanks.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by that. If you are referring to the drop shadow, that should come "out of the box" on Android 5.0. On Android 4.4 and below, you might look at how `CardView` implements its fake drop shadow and attempt to reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity in the above comment. I'll try again. The regular toolbar takes up the full width. But in the above picture, the toolbar is not full width. Thus giving it a 'detached' standalone feel.

Comment: Well, I haven't played with `Toolbar` yet, but since it is an ordinary widget, I would assume it responds to things like `android:layout_width`.

Comment: Yes. I guess I should treat it just like another Viewgroup. Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 7):

I've worked with the Toolbar before and all the comments from CommonsWare are absolutely correct.

The `Toolbar` widget (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) have absolutely nothing special or different than any other `Viewgroup` and does not behave differently than any other ViewGroup.

Put it inside a `FrameLayout`, put a `layout_margin` parameter on it, make the `layout_width` NOT `match_parent` and that's it.

Put it inside an `LinearLayout` with `orientation=horizontal` and you can use the `layout_weight` to control the size in percentage. Or just use plain `dip` if that suits your needs.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are following the Material Design concept I am assuming your are using [Coordinator Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) as your **Main Layout** and Not Frame Layout.

Before anything else we need to declare the important dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

### Expected/Similar Output

[image]

### XML snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frmlyout_locationnote_mapholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- You can add your Map here-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgvw_locationnote_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tlbr_locationnote_mainmenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_locationnote_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_white_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/frmlyout_locationnote_mapholder"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think Mark's suggestion for picking up the CardView "look" in the comment above deserves this derivative answer:

Just put a `Toolbar` in a `CardView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/map_toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/whatever_you_want"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#324">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/wld_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    **android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"**
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add the following code....

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    >
     //add whatever elements you want to add in here.
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Please edit the code into a codeblock and provide more detail to support your answer

Answer (score 0):

### **Here is the code for the floating toolbar, just copy and paste.**

This is an example of a floating toolbar using Appcompat, It can be working under many layouts like Relative, Coordinator, or DrawerLayout. You can increase elevation to make it more effective.

[floating toolbar with Edit text or Search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZbRT.png)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">


<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:background="@drawable/floating_toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

<EditText
    android:gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_no_border"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search here.." />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>       
</LinearLayout>
```

---

drawable/floating_toolbar.xml file for set background shadows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#6FA5A5A5" />
        <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

---

drawable/edit_text_no_border.xml file for EditText without an outline box or bottom border to make it clean matching background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners  android:radius="0px"/>
    <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

Emoji = ThumbsUp