# How to customize the color of the caret of the expanded-search-action-item?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, searchview, caret

### Background

I've made a few adjustments to my tiny app, so that it would follow the material design guidelines better.

### The problem

I have a search action item, and the action bar is blue, but when clicking the search action item, I can barely see the caret (where the text is being entered).

I would like to change it, maybe to white (like the text color).

### What I've tried

I've tried looking at the code of the support library, searching for a function that will allow me to customize the caret's color, but I couldn't find a working solution.

I've tried to use "searchViewStyle" as one of the theme's items, and create a new style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
...
```

But none of what I've found seem fit for this.

The weird thing is that when using "**Theme.AppCompat.Light**" instead of "**Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar**" , the caret's color has changed (to green).

### The question

How do I change the color of the text caret of the search action item (AKA SearchView) ?

---

EDIT: I've found out that it's possible to set "colorControlActivated" for the toolbar, as such:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarTheme</item>
.... 

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FFffffff</item>
</style>
```

Seems to work, but does it affect other things, except for the caret of the search item? If so, which ones? and is it possible to affect only the caret ?

Comment: Does setting `colorControlActivated` (in the main theme) help?

Comment: updated question. Seems to work, but I still have a question about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per official design guidelines, caret should be tinted (API>21) with the reference in `android:colorControlActivated` (`colorControlActivated` through `support-v7`). As you discovered it is automatically tinted like so.

`colorControlActivated` is used by default in several widgets. As the name suggest, it will be the color of:

- an activated CheckBox;
- a focused EditText;
- selected RadioButtons;

and so on. I can't recall all places it is used in, but if you managed to apply it to the toolbar only, it shouldn't have any other application than the widgets you put in your `Menu` (the SearchView for example). It could (not sure) have some impact on contextual action bars.

If you want to have full control over the caret, you could also provide your own drawable:

```
<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/my_drawable</item>
```

This works for API>12.

Comment: Wait, so the official guidelines say I should use the same color for the caret as other places on the app? But this means I should choose a color that's very different than the one of the toolbar, because otherwise it would blend with the one of the toolbar. However, if I do this, it would be weird to have it on other views of the app... I've looked at some of Google's apps, and I've noticed they made the search-EditText to be white (even with reveal effect). is this ok ? if so, how do I do this?

Comment: I think EditText and widgets are not meant to be (frequently) used in toolbars. I don't know if I understand your question. If you want the caret to be white, just set `colorControlActivated` to white in the action bar theme. That's totally legit if `colorControlActivated` and `colorPrimary` are really close. If you are referring to the white search box (e.g., play store or google maps) that's just a Toolbar with some padding and there are already question on this topic here.

Comment: Can you please show the question? Sounds interesting and I might use this (though I'm not sure what it has to do with padding). About the current question, ok, I'll now tick your answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28798699/4288782 this might be one. In a few words, use a Toolbar with custom margins to make it look floating.

Comment: This is not what I meant. I meant that: the action bar color isn't white at first. When clicking the search-action-item, the action item becomes a white EditText using a reveal effect, like on the Play Store app. This way, you can avoid setting a special "colorControlActivated" value for the action bar.