# Android - How can I achieve this type of toolbar?

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I notice this type of toolbar used in recent apps on PlayStore, and I need to achieve this.

[image]

I know how to create a simple toolbar in XML.

**Simple Toolbar**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:theme="@style/about_toolbar"
            >
... 

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I seems like a toolbar with padding.

So I'm not entirely sure.
Please can someone who has done this help me out !

Comment: did you try adding a margin?

Comment: Thanks @DavidMedenjak, margin worked, but Its missing the shadow and the UI feel which is the image i posted.

Comment: Check my answer for the shadow

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798699/floating-toolbar-with-appcompat/28799795#28799795

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example with cardView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#bcbcbc"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: It worked, Please remove the 1st example so as not to confuse people !

Comment: Done glad to help you