# Android - non-floating toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

my problem is, that with appcompat I am able only to create a toolbar, which is floating. In my scenario this looks pretty ugly. Could not find any tutorial/solution, that would allow to create toolbar a non-floatable one. Do you have any ideas?

My current implementation:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    />
```

UPDATE:

by floating I mean, that it's not aligned to top and right left border. Instead it's just flying attached to nothing.

[Floating Toolbar with Appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798699/floating-toolbar-with-appcompat) this is a sample with floating toolbar.

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html in image here here is non-floating toolbar.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "floating" more? Is there a particular graphic that makes it appear to "float" (like a shadow), or is there a behavior that you are observing that you don't like?

Comment: Thanks forthe interest. I updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the complete layout XML, it is hard to provide a good answer, but based on your description of the problem, it sounds like the root layout (or whatever View contains your `Toolbar` has padding set on it.

Remove all padding from the Toolbar's parent and you should get what you are looking for.

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly what I was looking for. I thought it is some Tollbar's specific behavior, that makes it floating. Haven't thought of padding, though. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

What about using this:

```
<Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorAccent"
        android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

or does it need to be of type `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` ?

You can find the tutorial here:
[non-floating Toolbar](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/)